# finding in less than O(n) time the max value while having quick insert / delete in a unordered list

Tags: c#, performance, data-structures

the code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        const int maxResult = 120; //this can change but hardcoded for this code

        static int poolPos;
        static double[] pool = new double[maxResult * 4];

        static int maxPos;
        static double[] result = new double[maxResult];


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for(int i = 0; i  < 100_000; ++i)
                Unlock();

            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            //Console.Read();
        }

        static void Unlock()
        {
            int total = maxResult;

            //reset array
            poolPos = 0;
            maxPos = 0;

            FindLock(4);


            while (total-- > 0)
            {
                int i = 0;

                double maxWeight = pool[0];
                int pos = 0;

                while (++i < poolPos) //O(n), can it be faster?
                    if (pool[i] >= maxWeight) //can have duplicate value, find latest max inserted
                        (maxWeight, pos) = (pool[i], i); //keep track

                result[maxPos++] = maxWeight; //store the result
                pool[pos] = pool[--poolPos]; //remove from array by swapping it with last item in the array
                FindLock();
            }
        }

        //simulate what feed the array
        //don't look at this unless something should be done at insert time
        static Random rnd = new Random(42); 
        static void FindLock(int add = -1)
        {
            if(add == -1)
            {
                add = rnd.Next(1, 4);
            }

            for(int i = 0;i<add;++i)
            {
                pool[poolPos++] = rnd.Next(-500, 500) / 100d;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

profiling result:
[image: profiling result]

based on the profiling, I'm trying to find a way to speed it up, all the solution that I found online use double stack or double queue so they only use head or tail value of the array, the code above can pick any item in the list that meet the requirement so I don't think I can use stack or queue.

Comment: Just wrap the unordered list in a new class that remembers the max value. If you need to be able to delete the max value and find the new max value, you will slow down when you request the max value after deleting it.

Comment: I don't believe your list is unordered, since your code finds the latest max value when their are duplicate max values. If it were truly unordered, your code wouldn't care which was found. OTOH, deleting by swapping with the last position loses that chronological ordering, so that seems contradictory...

Answer (score 1):

With a "priority queue" or "max heap", the table is partially sorted, and many operations are O(log(N)):

- max (or min, but not both)
- insert one row
- delete one row

Item 1 is known to be greater than items 2 and 3.  Item 1 is always the max.
Item 2 is known to be greater than items 4 and 5.
Item 3 is known to be greater than items 6 and 7.
etc.  In general:
Item [k] is known to be greater than items [2*k] and [2*k+1].

Inserts and deletes get a little tricky since you want to keep the table compact.

One of many references:  https://www.techiedelight.com/introduction-priority-queues-using-binary-heaps/

The structure can be handy if items are coming and going a lot, but the important action is to grab the max value.  Accessing the max value is O(1), but deleting it is O(N).

Answer (score 0):

By definition, if you're working with an unordered list, finding an item is always going to be O(1) in the best case, and O(n) in the worst case.

You can use a hash table to get better lookup speeds, as well as insert/delete. However the hash algorithm itself can be just as expensive as iterating through your list, so proceed with caution. Depending on the use-case, a hash table might be the way to go.

Comment: since the list can contain duplicate entries, i don't think hash table is a solution

Comment: sure it is, you just need to handle for collisions, as with any other hash table

Comment: there is, by definition, no other possible way to solve this problem with an unordered list of elements

Comment: @Fredou Your code is mind boggling. You have a method `FindLock` that returns nothing, and a method `Unlock` that is doing all sorts of funny things, except from changed the state from locked to unlocked in any meaningful way. It is not the kind of code that invites to dive-in and study. I wish you could simplify and minimalize it a bit.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias the findlock is just a way to feed new value into an array(pool), you could rename it to FeedThePool (that would be in fact a better name), the unlock actually "unlock" by removing the value from that same array (pool) in 2 step. first is copying the value into another array(result) then moving(swapping) the value at the end of the array(pool) and decreasing the capacity, making that value unavailable and would be overwritten by the next pass of unlock. the issue here is finding an efficient way of keeping track of the latest max value of the array(pool)

Comment: An hash won’t help find the maximum value

Comment: @Phil1970 - max or min, in an unordered list in less than O(n) time. Unless you hold a reference to the max and min, the OP is asking the impossible. 

A hash won't help the min/max problem, but it will help the insert/delete speeds.